# Flask routing gives 404 error when link should be routed

Tags: python, html, flask

I am going insane over this.
Im using Flask to create a simple website for me and my friends to share and organize school material. Example of folder structure is: uploads/"name of course"/"type of document"/"document.txt/docs/pdf"
In every course folder, theres 3 folders, one for notes ("ant"), one for books("books") and one for old exams ("tentor").

```
@app.route('/<folder>/<filename>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def download(folder, filename):
    print("test")
    return send_from_directory(path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], folder), filename, as_attachment=True)
```

If i click on a assigment, I get redirected to for example "http://x.x.x.x:xxxx/E0009N/ant/Lecture%201.pdf" which seems correct but I get error 404 not found!
This file do exist in uploads\E0009N\ant. The print("test") never gets excecuted.

```
<body>
<h1>{{ folder }}</h1>
<form action="{{ url_for('logout') }}" method="post">
  <button type="submit">Log Out</button>
</form>
<div class="container">
  <ul class="file-list">
    {% if books is defined and books|length > 0 %}
      <h2>Böcker</h2>
      {% set bookpath = folder + "/books" %}
      {% for book in books %}
        <li>
          <a href="{{ url_for('download', folder=bookpath, filename=book) }}" >
            {{ book }}
          </a>
        </li>
      {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <ul class="file-list">
    {% if anteckningar is defined and anteckningar|length > 0 %}
      <h2>Material och anteckningar</h2>
      {% set antpath = folder + "/ant" %}
      {% for ant in anteckningar %}
        <li>
          <a href="{{ url_for('download', folder=antpath, filename=ant) }}">
            {{ ant }}
          </a>
        </li>
      {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <ul class="file-list">
    {% if tentor is defined and tentor|length > 0 %}
      <h2>Tentor</h2>
      {% set tentapath = folder + "/tentor" %}
      {% for tenta in tentor %}
        <li>
          <a href="{{ url_for('download', folder=tentapath, filename=tenta) }}">
            {{ tenta }}
          </a>
        </li>
      {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
  </ul>
</div>
```

Didn't sleep bcs of this.. If anyone can help me solve this I owe you my life.. Thank you!

Edit, here is the folder() function if it could help:

```
@app.route('/<folder>/')
@login_required
def folder(folder):
    antfolder = folder + "/ant"
    anteckningar = [f for f in     listdir(path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], antfolder)) if     path.isfile(path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], antfolder, f))]
    booksfolder = folder + "/books"
    books = [f for f in listdir(path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], booksfolder)) if path.isfile(path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], booksfolder, f))]
    tentorfolder = folder + "/tentor"
    tentor = [f for f in listdir(path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], tentorfolder)) if path.isfile(path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], tentorfolder, f))]
    anteckningar.sort()
    books.sort()
    tentor.sort()
    return render_template('folder.html', anteckningar=anteckningar, books=books, tentor=tentor,folder=folder)
```

Answer (score 1):

The route is not recognized due to additional separators contained in the variables and a 404 error is thrown.

I recommend declaring the type when using [variable rules](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/quickstart/#variable-rules) for path information. You can also make your work easier if you summarize the path to the file in advance. This means that only one variable for the URL is required for downloading.

The following example offers you the files, which are listed by folder, for downloading.

```py
from flask import (
    Flask, 
    render_template, 
    send_from_directory
)
import os 
import pathlib

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_mapping(
    UPLOAD_FOLDER=os.path.join(app.instance_path, 'uploads')
)

@app.route('/<path:folder>')
def folder(folder):
    upload_folder = app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER']
    anteckningar, books, tentor = [
        [
            {
                'filename': f.name, 
                'filepath': str(f.relative_to(upload_folder))
            } 
            for f in pathlib.Path(upload_folder, folder, subfolder).iterdir() 
            if f.is_file() and not f.name.startswith('.')
        ] 
        for subfolder in ['ant', 'books', 'tentor']
    ]
    return render_template('folder.html', **locals())

@app.route('/download/<path:filename>')
def download(filename):
    return send_from_directory(
        app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], 
        filename, 
        as_attachment=True
    )
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>{{ folder }}</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>{{ folder }}</h1>
    {% if books %}
    <div class="container">
        <h2>Böcker</h2>
        <ul class="file-list">
            {% for book in books | sort(attribute='filename') %}
            <li><a href="{{ url_for('download', filename=book.filepath) }}" download>{{ book.filename }}</a></li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </div>
    {% endif %}

    {% if anteckningar %}
    <div class="container">
        <h2>Material och anteckningar</h2>
        <ul class="file-list">
            {% for ant in anteckningar | sort(attribute='filename') %}
            <li><a href="{{ url_for('download', filename=ant.filepath) }}" download>{{ ant.filename }}</a></li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </div>
    {% endif %}

    {% if tentor %}
    <div class="container">
        <h2>Tentor</h2>
        <ul class="file-list">
            {% for tenta in tentor | sort(attribute='filename') %}
            <li><a href="{{ url_for('download', filename=tenta.filepath) }}" download>{{ tenta.filename }}</a></li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </div>
    {% endif %}
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This kind of worked! However, the file it tried to download is wrong. This is a example of the file and path it tried to download; "E0009N_ant_Lecture 1.htm".  The "/" seen to become "_" for some reason and insted of .pdf it tries to download some ".htm" file.. (E0009N/ant/Lecture 1.pdf is the correct one) Thanks for the response!

Comment: I tried to recreate your problem with my code and can't confirm your findings. The file "E0009N/ant/Lecture 1.pdf" is downloaded for me.

Comment: It seems like the href attribute is not set correctly. Both the quotation marks and the call to `url_for` should prevent the value from being misinterpreted.